# View doesn't dispatch touch event to its parent

Tags: android, events, onclick, touch

I have a framelayout which I make clickable (android:clickable="true")

I add this framelayout to another view (lets call it "view2").
I set onClickListener to view2.. but, the listener isn't being triggered

when i remove android:clickable="true", it is being triggered!

how can i handle it? 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to handle clicks on the `FrameLayout`, you need to `setOnClickListener()` on the `FrameLayout` itself and not on its parent.

Also, if you call `setOnClickListener()` on the `FrameLayout`, then there is no need to set `android:clickable="true"`, as it's set automatically.

Comment: I need the touch events in both the child and its parent. For the child i need "android:clickable="true" because I add it a selector in order to change its background. And for the parent i need onClickListener in order to launch another activity.

Answer (score 0):

make your view 2 to have

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

 android:focusable="false"
```

That's all.